# Health Check keeps failing for ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I am currently trying to deploy 2 ECS services on a single EC2 instance for test environment.

### Here is what I have done so far:

- Successfully created 2 Security Groups for Load Balancer and EC2 instance.

###### My EC2 Security Group

[image: EC2 Security Group]

###### My ALB Security Group

[image: ALB Security Group]

- Successfully created 2 different Task Definitions for my 2 applications, all Spring Boot application. First application is running on port 8080, Container Port in Task Definition is also 8080. The second application is running on port 8081, Container Port in Task Definition is also 8081.
- Successfully created an ECS cluster with an Auto-Scaling Group as Capacity Provider. The cluster also recognizes the Container Instance created from Auto-Scaling Group (I am using **t2.micro** since it is in free-tier package). Attached created Security Group to EC2 instance.

###### My EC2 Security Group

[image: ECS Infrastructure]

- Successfully created an ALB with 2 forward listeners 8080 and 8081 configured to 2 different Target Groups for each service. Attached created Security Group to ALB.

### Here is how the ECS behaves with my services:

- I attempted to create 2 new services. First service mapped with port 8080 on ALB. The second one mapped with port 8081 on ALB. Each of them have different Target Group but the Health Check configurations are the same

###### Health Check Configuration for Service 1

[image: Health Check Configuration for Service 2]

###### Health Check Configuration for Service 2

[image: Health Check Configuration for Service 2]

- The first service was deployed pretty smooth, health check returned success on the first try.
- However, for the second service, I use the exact same configuration as the first one, just a different port listener on ALB and the application container running on a different port number as well (which I believe that it should not be a problem). The service attempted 10 times before it fails the deployment and I noticed getting this repeated error message: `service <service_name> instance <instance_id> port <port_number> is unhealthy in target-group <target_group_name> due to (reason Health checks failed)`.
- This did not happen with my first service with the same configuration. The weird thing is that when I attempted to send a request the ALB domain name on port 8081, the application on the second service seems to be working fine without any error. It is just that the Unhealthy Check keeps throwing my service off.

I went over bunch of posts and nothing really helps with the current situation. Also, it is kind of dumb since I cannot dig any further details rather than this info in this image below.
[image: Health Check Status appears Error]

Anyone has any suggestion to resolve this problem? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: How did you change the port number on the second service? If you just changed it in the task definition, the software running in the container will still be listening to the other port. You have to configure the software itself to listen on that port. The setting in the task definition just tells ECS what port that software listens on.

Comment: Hey @MarkB, for Task Definition, the first application is running on port 8080, so my Container Port is configured to be 8080. For the second software, since it is running on port 8081, my Container Port in Task Definition is configured to 8081. I edited the post as well!

Comment: Check the service events. What is the specific healthcheck failure? You can find the events in the console or by using [the describe-services API](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/describe-services.html#examples). You might see something like "healthcheck timed out" or you might see something like "failed with status code 500" -- this will help diagnose the issue further. It may also be helpful to check the logs for the service tasks.

Comment: @sytech I already checked the log event and the only useful data point for debugging that I found was `service <service_name> instance <instance_id> port <random_port_number> is unhealthy in target-group <target_group_name> due to (reason Health checks failed)`, which seems to be odd as I was still able to access the endpoint at that specific port and get 200 OK status. Heath Status Details is also not very helpful, as it only gives "Health checks failed".

Comment: Do you see the healthcheck request from the ALB in the service logs? Also verify in the logs that the listen port is correct.